# Woocommerce product variations layout change

Tags: woocommerce

I want to make a small change on the single-product page about displaying variations.

Normally variations are displayed like this as html.

```
    <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>

<tr>
<td class="label"><label for="group-size">Group Size</label></td>
<td class="value">
<select id="group-size" class="" name="attribute_group-size" data-attribute_name="attribute_group-size">
<option value="">Chose an options</option>
<option value="1 Person" >1 Person</option>
<option value="2 persons" >2 persons</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="label"><label for="type-of-activity">Type of Activity</label></td>
<td class="value">
<select id="tipo-de-actividad" class="" name="attribute_tipo-de-actividad" data-attribute_name="attribute_type-of-activity">
<option value="">Chose an option</option>
<option value="Walking" >Walking</option>
<option value="With car" >with car</option>
</select>
<a class="reset_variations" href="#">Clean the selections</a>
</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

But I want to have like this

```
    <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>

<tr>
<td class="label"><label for="group-size">Group Size</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="value">
<select id="group-size" class="" name="attribute_group-size" data-attribute_name="attribute_group-size">
<option value="">Chose an options</option>
<option value="1 Person" >1 Person</option>
<option value="2 persons" >2 persons</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="label"><label for="type-of-activity">Type of Activity</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="value">
<select id="tipo-de-actividad" class="" name="attribute_tipo-de-actividad" data-attribute_name="attribute_type-of-activity">
<option value="">Chose an option</option>
<option value="Walking" >Walking</option>
<option value="With car" >with car</option>
</select>
<a class="reset_variations" href="#">Clean the selections</a>
</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Means that i wantto have the labels inside a row just above the options.

How we can do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the solution myself.

There is variable.php in
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart

I opened that file

ı have changed

```
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo sanitize_title( $attribute_name ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); ?></label></td>
                        <td class="value">
                            <?php
                                $selected = isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) ? wc_clean( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) : $product->get_variation_default_attribute( $attribute_name );
                                wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( array( 'options' => $options, 'attribute' => $attribute_name, 'product' => $product, 'selected' => $selected ) );
                                echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . __( 'Clear selection', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' : '';
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

to

```
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo sanitize_title( $attribute_name ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); ?></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
                        <td class="value">
                            <?php
                                $selected = isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) ? wc_clean( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) : $product->get_variation_default_attribute( $attribute_name );
                                wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( array( 'options' => $options, 'attribute' => $attribute_name, 'product' => $product, 'selected' => $selected ) );
                                echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . __( 'Clear selection', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' : '';
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Result was as i like.

Sorry for disturbing you.

Comment: Never ever ever modify plugin core files.

Comment: @Daniel, so offer an alternative fo the OP, who has done a good job of reporting back on the issue with an answer. Woocommerce's system of hooks and actions put the HTML all over the place.  Frankly, if a core file can be modified to create new static HTML, performance-wise that could be better than a bunch of remove_actions and add_actions. Perhaps better just to point out that the OP needs to be careful when updating Woocommerce, or even better copying it to the file to the theme (though even that comes with some overhead).

Comment: @MikeA - no, it's not. It's horrible practice and you should not be arguing in favour of it. You should NEVER modify plugin files. Either override what you need via hooks or make use of Woocommerce's templating (where you can override template files, by creating a woocommerce directory in your theme files). See https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
Similarly to how you should never modify files in node_modules... it's a very similar concept.